# Openldap naming context issue with Apache directory studio?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, apacheds

I have installed openldap in linux machine, but when i am trying to connect it through Apache Directory studio ,I am getting no any child for **Root DSE**

[image]

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Now if i am trying to import any `LDIF` file i am getting

> Error while importing LDIF
>    - [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge] java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior
>   knowledge]    at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1278)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$9(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1246)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1107)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.createEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:948)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdifRecord(ImportLdifRunnable.java:465)

Answer (score 2):

You probably did not configure or create the suffix entry. You need to do that, go to the `slapd.conf` and check that you have defined `suffix` like:

```
suffix "dc=example,dc=com"
```

Then you need to (re)start your server, and add that entry to the LDAP database using `ldapadd`. So the LDIF file to accomplish that would be (*example.ldif*):

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: example
```

And the command to add it to the database would be something like:

```
ldapadd -x -D "<rootdn>" -W -f example.ldif
```

Of course, your suffix can be anything you like (e.g. o=company,c=us), but you need to change the LDIF file accordingly.

Comment: Hi @zoran Thanks for the reply ,issue found with ldif file where i used wrong `dc` name .I was using `dc=tm` while it would be `dc=tn`